# Give two integer vectors in c++ (same size and type), I'd like to sort one from smallest to largest element and change the order of the second vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, std

Give two integer vectors in c++ (same size), I'd like to sort one of my vectors from smallest to largest element and change the order of the second vector respectively.

How can I achieve this without using boost library?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean that if the fourth element of array one goes first, then fourth element of array two should go first too?

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate of the other question because this question says "without using boost" while the other one said "preferably using the STL or Boost."

Comment: @DouglasZare: "Not using Boost" is half of "STL _[sic]_ or Boost", and the accepted answer does not use Boost. In fact, only two of the nine excellent answers refer to Boost (not counting the suggestion of `boost::tie` and `boost::tuple`, as they are both now in the C++ Standard Library) but only to the Standard Library. I don't see the problem. This question was asked and answered long ago.

Comment: Based on the answers for "How do I ..." previous question, you can either pair up the vectors, or place at least one of the vectors in a class and use a function operator (functor) or lambda function for std::sort, that sorts a vector of indices into the first vector, then use those indices to reorder the second vector according to the vector of indices.

Comment: Another option is to implement your own sort instead of using std::sort or std::stable_sort, so that the custom sort can work with multiple vectors.

Answer (score 2):

You can restructure your code so that, instead of two vectors of integers, it uses a vector of `S`, where `S` is a structure containing two integers. Then you can define a specific `operator<` to be used by the sort function.

This has the advantage that the strict coupling between the two sets of data is clearly stated in the way they are stored.

Comment: Someone voted this down. I'd like to know why, since this is what I do every time I run into this common situation. If there is some reason not to do this, please elaborate.

Comment: I don't think this answer directly answers the original question. First answer the original, then give an alternative implementation. If not, an alternative should be left as a comment.

Comment: But this answer solves the problem that is behind the question. And that's the way that problem is almost always solved, because it is simple, clear and efficient.

Comment: It's a good idea and a good approach but indeed you did not answer the question as posed.